# TeXShop Error Preventing Compile

Tags: errors, installing, mactex

I installed the BasicTeX, wrote my assignment, and compiled it as a PDF. 
I then was struggling to add the graphs similar to this: https://texblog.org/2015/09/16/drawing-trees-with-tikzpgf-and-lualatex/. 
I was told to download MacTeX. I installed the file, rebooted, and opened the assignment in TeXShop again.

```
The following error came up:
Can't find required tool.
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdtex does not exist. TeXShop is a front end for TeX, but you also need a TeX distribution. Perhaps such a distribution was not installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to http://tug.org/mactex and follow the instructions to install MacTeX or BasicTeX.
```

Edit: this is literally a copy/paste of what the error is, I did not re-type it.

I spoke to pavonia on IRC who went through the terminal method with me. The file compiles into PDF format when I do it through the terminal.

Edit: now the file is not compiling on terminal.

I saw 2 threads similar to this but those settings recommended are already what my settings are. I'm unsure what to do in this case please.

Comment: `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdtex ` was that a typo for `pdftex` ?

Comment: Assuming that was a typo... what OS version are you using? How old is the copy of the MacTeX package you used? If you are using a fresh copy of Sierra (i.e., not an update from an earlier version of macOS) you might try to download and install the FixLinks.pkg from <[http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/)>.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.